# Query on entity has an arrray compared to other array using Spring Framework MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

So basically I have this issue, I have this object

```
Post {
   "title": "string", 
   "categoryIds": ["code1", "code2"] 
}
```

I represent it in this entity class

```
public class Post {

    @Id
    private String title;
    private Collection<String> categoryIds;

    //constructors getters and setters
```

And I have to perform a search where the input is a list of categoryIds and I have to print the posts with this category

It shoud look somehing like

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categoryIds").any(iDs));
```

Is there a way to do a query that says

```
idsCollectionField <is there any that is contained> inputListOfIds
```

So far I have this

```
private NewsletterDTO getNewsletter(Collection<String> relatedCodes) {
        Collection<NotificationDTO> notificationDTOS = new ArrayList<>();

        if (relatedCodes != null) {
            List<Post> posts;
            Query query = new Query();
            Criteria criteria = null;

            /*
            for (String category : relatedCodes) {
                if (criteria == null) {
                    criteria = Criteria.where("categoryCodes").in(relatedCodes);
                } else {
                    criteria = criteria.orOperator(
                            criteria,
                            Criteria.where("categoryCodes").in(relatedCodes));
                }
            }*/

            criteria = Criteria.where("categoryCodes").all(relatedCodes);
            query.addCriteria(criteria);
            posts = mongoOps.find(query, Post.class);
            query = new Query();
            criteria = Criteria.where("categoryCodes").in(relatedCodes);
            query.addCriteria(criteria);
            posts = mongoOps.find(query, Post.class);
            query = new Query();
            criteria = Criteria.where("categoryCodes").nin(relatedCodes);
            query.addCriteria(criteria);
            posts = mongoOps.find(query, Post.class);

            if (posts != null) {
                //transformations
            }
        }


        return new NewsletterDTO(notificationDTOS);
    }
```

I don't have a lot of experience en MongoDB nor Spring Framework,

Comment: Try
`query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categoryIds").in(iDs));`

Comment: @Veeram I added that but the result is an empty collection, I checked with a find all and there are posts with categories
iDs is a collection too

Comment: Can you please update your post with complete code that I can run on my side and verify ?

Comment: @Veeram updated all the code

Comment: @Veeram You were right I fixed it with     query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categoryIds").in(iDs))